# Is the Raspberry Pi 4 already supported by the google assistant library?

Tags: raspberry-pi4, google-assistant-sdk

When I put in the `pip install` command to get the library it gives me this error: ERROR:

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-assistant-library==1.0.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for google-assistant-library==1.0.1
```

the `pip install` command I used:

`python -m pip install google-assistant-library==1.0.1`

I hope someone can help me.

I did every thing what the google page:
(https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/guides/service/python/embed/setup )

Told me, and I get this error after the `python -m pip install google-assistant-library==1.0.1` command it gives me an error.

Comment: python3 -m pip install google-assistant-library==1.0.1 or python3 -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-library